# airflow crontab expression schedule issue

Tags: cron, airflow

i want to set dag schedule to "At minute 0 past hour 9, 12, 16, and 19 on every day-of-week from Monday through Saturday"

so i use cron expression like this `0 9,12,16,19 * * 1-6`
i check this cron expression in [cron guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_9,12,16,19_*_*_1-6) and the expression turned out to be correct.

but when i run schedule dag, it work at 0:00 am.
I don't think it should work at that time. i can't find why it works at 0:00 am

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you mean by "it worked"? what worked? do you refer to a DAG starting to run but with the wrong execution_date? Please describe better what happened and why it's not according to your expectations.

Comment: It's possible you are not taking into account the timezone of Airflow's server and therefore you are seeing the discrepancy between the hours.